# How to create a windows batch file script that can run an application from 2 different drives. (using conditional statements)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script that can run an application from 2 drives.

For example, it can run on drive X but if drive X is disconnected, it goes to drive Z (vice-versa)

thanks!

Comment: kindly do add what you have tried so far so that we may help you better

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist z:\ (
   rem run from volume z:
) else (
   rem run from other volume
)
```

How to get all valid volumes:

```
fsutil fsinfo drives
```

Comment: C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE is the program

x:\menu\ntmcmenu - path containing oracle forms

Answer (score 0):

first check program exist or not
if exist run program otherwise open from another drive

```
@echo off
if exist {C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE} (
    rem file exists
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE 
echo exist
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
START D:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE 
echo not
)
exit
```

---

according to your comment i think code should be ;

```
@echo off
    if exist X:\ (
        rem drive exists
    C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu

    ) else (
        rem drive doesn't exist
    C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu

    )
    exit
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that... however it does not work or i'm just wrong... not really familiar with batch scripting 

here's what i wrote, however the other condition does not support what i really wanted.

if exist C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu 
(
   SKIP="C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu"
)

else
(
   C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu
)

Comment: C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu i can't recognize this.
C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE is the program then what is x:\menu\ntmcmenu  parameter or what ?

Comment: can you tell me how did you run C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu from command line.then i can help you

Comment: C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE is the program 

x:\menu\ntmcmenu - path containing oracle forms

Comment: type C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu or C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu in cmd and tell me what happen
if it open forum or what you expect tell me

Comment: it opens... 

this is my original script. however, when i disconnect x, it could not proceed with w running the application.

if exist C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE x:\menu\ntmcmenu 
(
   SKIP="C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu"
)

else
(
   C:\Oracle\806\BIN\ifrun60.EXE w:\menu\ntmcmenu
)

Comment: @user3404769 could you accept this as correct answer